# Sorting custom post types depends on ACF Date Field

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-post-type

My task is to sort all the custom post types ('audio', 'video', 'webdev' etc.) gathered by taxonomy 'portfolio' or by any tag. And I do it with following code.

```
    add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_post_types_sort' );

    function custom_post_types_sort( $query ) {

        if ( is_tax('portfolio') || is_tag() ) {

            $cptui_post_types = cptui_get_post_type_slugs();

            // Sort portfolio taxonomy posts by project start date.
            $query->set( 'post_type', $cptui_post_types );
            $query->set( 'order', 'DESC' );
            $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value_num' );
            $query->set( 'meta_key', 'date' );
        }
    }

?>
```

Everything works fine except one thing. My menu not showing on the taxonomy template. I'm using taxonomy-portfolio.php template to display pages.

I assume this is happening because of query modification.

```
<?php 
    /**
    *    Portfolio Taxonomy Template
    */
    get_header();
?>

<section class="portfolio-template swiper">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper postfolio-list">
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/breadcrumbs' ); ?>
            <div class="portfolio-project-items">
                <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
                    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                        <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'portfolio-item' ); ?>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: IMHO it is more likely you are not including the menu on the taxonomy-portfolio.php...  Does the menu show up when you comment out the custom_post_types_sort() filter? Please share the code of this template (edit your question).

Comment: (have you got WP_Debug activated? -> https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/)

Comment: @jasie, my menu is included in separate template. Yes, menu is showing up when the action is commented.

Comment: Then I would expect some PHP warning, did you check WP_Debug?

Comment: What is the value of `$cptui_post_types`?

Comment: Unfortunately it not displaying any errors.

Comment: $cptui_post_types this is array of custom post type slugs.

Comment: Please change it to this and tell me if the menu shows up: `$query->set( 'post_type', 'audio' );`

Comment: Also, what happens if you comment out all content of custom_post_types_sort() and then you comment in one line after the other, each time executing the func and checking the result (classical debugging)?

Comment: All the same. The reason why I'm using array is because it sort all kind of custom posts all together.

Comment: another idea: did you try `$query->is_main_query()`? see https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/post-types/working-with-custom-post-types/#altering-the-main-query

Comment: You're right, it should be checked is it main query or not. Thanks a lot! I've updated a code a bit.

Comment: You're welcome. But you should not add the fix to your question. this way, it cannot help others with the same problem. keep the code in the error-causing state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this

```
if ( is_tax('portfolio') || is_tag() ) {
```

by this

```
if ( ( is_tax('portfolio') || is_tag() ) && $query->is_main_query() ) {
```

Check the docs: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_main_query/

> This function is most commonly used within hooks to distinguish
> WordPress’ main query (for a page, post, or archive) from a
> custom/secondary query.

Does this fix your problem?